# Counterexample to $L^1$-boundedness of the maximal operator $f \mapsto f^\#$ with $f^{\sharp}(x):=\sup_{Q\ni x}\frac{1}{|Q|}\int_{Q}|f-(f)_{Q}|dy$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, harmonic-analysis

My question concerns the sharp maximal operator, mapping a locally integrable function $f\colon\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}$ to $f^{\sharp}\colon \mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}$, where $$f^{\sharp}(x):=\sup_{Q\ni x}\frac{1}{|Q|}\int_{Q}|f-(f)_{Q}|dy,$$ the $\sup$ running over all cubes with sides parallel to the coordinate axes and containing $x$.

Similar to the Hardy-Littlewood maximal operator which maps $L^{1}$ to weak-$L^{1}$, but not $L^{1}$ to $L^{1}$, I guess that the sharp maximal operator does not map $L^{1}$ to $L^{1}$. The standard example for this fact with respect to the Hardy Littlewood maximal operator, namely, the indicator function of the unit cube in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ does not seem to serve as a counterexample in this situation.

**My question:** Is there a similar "cheap" counterexample which shows that the sharp maximal operator does not map $L^{1}$ to $L^{1}$ - I would appreciate this very much! I've tried to find a solution to this issue in the web, but all references do not deal with this, so that I guess that it's either entirely trivial and I don't see it - or one does have a bound $\|f^{\sharp}\|_{L^{1}}\leq C \|f\|_{L^{1}}$.

However, referring to *Variable Lebesgue Spaces* of Cruz-Uribe & Fiorenza (Birkhaeuser 2013), p. 230, one has $\|f\|_{L^{p}}\leq c\|f^{\sharp}\|_{L^{p}}$ for all $f\in L^{p}$, $1\leq p<\infty$. Since $f^{\sharp}\leq C Mf$ with $Mf$ the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function pointwisely, one would obtain $\|f\|_{L^{p}}\leq c \|f^{\sharp}\|_{L^{p}}\leq C \|Mf\|_{L^{p}}\leq C'\|f\|_{L^{p}}$ provided $1<p<\infty$ which implies that the norms $\|\cdot\|_{L^{p}}$ and $\|(\cdot)^{\sharp}\|_{L^{p}}$ are equivalent, but somehow I cannot image that this remains valid for $p=1$ (which would be the case if one had a bound of $f^{\sharp}$ in $L^{1}$-norm against the $L^{1}$-norm of $f$).

Answer (score 4):

Consider $n=1$ and 
$$
f\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
0, & x\leq-1,\\
-1, & -1<x\leq0,\\
1, & 0<x\leq1,\\
0, & x>1.
\end{cases}
$$
For $x\in\mathbb{R}$ with $\left|x\right|\geq1$, we then have $x\in\left[-\left|x\right|,\left|x\right|\right]=:Q_{x}$
with $Q_{x}\supset\left[-1,1\right]$ which implies $\left(f\right)_{Q_{x}}=\left(f\right)_{\left[-1,1\right]}=0$
and thus
\begin{eqnarray*}
f^{\#}\left(x\right) & \geq & \frac{1}{\left|Q_{x}\right|}\int_{Q_{x}}\left|f\left(y\right)\right|\,{\rm d}y\\
 & = & \frac{1}{2\left|x\right|}\cdot\int_{-1}^{1}\left|f\left(y\right)\right|\,{\rm d}y\\
 & = & \frac{1}{\left|x\right|},
\end{eqnarray*}
which easily implies
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}f^{\#}\left(x\right)\,{\rm d}x\geq\int_{1}^{\infty}f^{\#}\left(x\right)\,{\rm d}x\geq\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}\,{\rm d}x=\infty
$$
and hence $f^{\#}\notin L^{1}$, although clearly $f\in L^{1}$.

I leave the modification for $n>1$ to you.